# How to invoke psql from liquibase executeCommand

Tags: liquibase, psql

Is there any way to execute psql command from liquibase?
Something like this:

```
<executeCommand executable="java">
   <arg value="-jar postgresql-42.4.0.jar"/>
   <arg value="psql \\copy my_tbl(col1,col2,col3) FROM 'db/changelog/files/my_tbl.csv'
            DELIMITER E'\\t' CSV HEADER QUOTE ''''  NULL '\N'  ESCAPE '''' "/>
</executeCommand>
```

I need to load multiple very big csv files during database build.

"loadData" is too slow and fails on outOfMemory for a big file

The solution would be to use sql copy command, but how to invoke it?

Comment: Does it do the same thing and timeout when you use loadUpdateData instead? https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/load-update-data.html

Comment: LoadUpdateData is too slow because it checks each record for existance before insert, and has the same memory problem